# Derivative of trace of Hadamard and dot product

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

Im struggling solving an equation and I have tried to find solution in the matrix cookbook but did not find a clue. How can I calculate the derivative of the equation which is a combination of Hadamard product and dot product:
$$tr(A\circ X.B(A\circ X.B)^T)$$
I am very appreciate your help.

Comment: Which symbol is Hadamard and which is dot product? Additionally, what operator precedence are you using? Meaning, does $A\circ X.B = (A\circ X) . B$ or $A\circ (X.B)$?

Comment: I mean : $$A\circ X.B = (A\circ X) . B$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y=(A\circ XB)$ and write the function using the product notation (:) for the trace.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm tr}(YY^T) = Y:Y \cr
d\phi &= 2Y:dY \cr
  &= 2Y:(A\circ dX\,B) \cr
  &= 2Y\circ A:dX\,B \cr
  &= 2(Y\circ A)B^T:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= 2(Y\circ A)B^T \cr
}$$
This assumes that the Hadamard product has the lowest precedence. 

If it actually has the highest precedence, then 
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= 2Y:(A\circ dX)\,B \cr
  &= 2YB^T:A\circ dX \cr
  &= 2(YB^T)\circ A:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= 2(YB^T)\circ A \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: I'm sorry if I understand it wrong, but does the result of the deriveative still contain $X$? (because $Y=(A\circ XB)$)

Comment: Yes, there's an $X$ hiding inside of that $Y$